# how does global variable increment work in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int counter = 0;

int f(){
    return counter++;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << f(); //output = 0
    std::cout << f()+f(); // output = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

This might be a silly question but why isn't `f()` equal to 1 instead of 0 in the first case?
I thought `counter++` was the same as `counter = counter + 1`?

Comment: Note that in the expression `f() + f()`, it's unspecified which function call executes first. The newbie might assume that expressions are evaluated inside out and left-to-right, but this is not guaranteed in C++. This can be an issue if you call `f() + g()` and either function causes side-effects that can affect the behavior of the other. The observable behavior of your program could change by making seemingly unrelated changes elsewhere that cause the optimizer to switch the order in which the functions are called!

Comment: Any C or C++ tutorial should explain the difference between `counter++` and `++counter`.

Comment: `++counter` is equivalent to `counter = counter + 1`.   `counter++` is not.

Comment: write a `g()` that's similar to `f()` and change to `std::cout << f()+g();`, strange things will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the difference between postfix and prefix notation. In postfix notation which is what you have currently it saves a copy of the variable and then increments the variable for any calls below the current call however at the current call it will appear to stay the same.

This is why when we have `std::cout << f(); //output = 0` it outputs 0 because counter will only increment after this line. If you change f to:

`int f() { return ++counter; }`

You will see the result you expected.

Answer (score 1):

No. `counter++` is closer to `(counter = counter + 1) - 1`

Comment: WOW. That is a new definition to me. I always though of postfix notation as a incremental operation set aside until the current line was done executing.

Comment: @HenriPrudhomme Note that this is not a definition. Merely some wordings hopefully understandable by any developer.

Answer (score 0):

first, Are you sure `f() + f()` results in `1`. I think it should be `3`.

Regarding your main question:

post increment works on a copy of the original value. so your function in f() is acting as:

```
int f()
{
   int temp = counter;
   counter = counter + 1;
   return temp;
}
```

or as cleverly noted by @kmkaplan:

```
int f()
{
   return (counter = counter + 1 ) - 1;
}
```

it is similar to the semantic of:

```
int f = 0;

cout << f++;  // f original value is first displayed.
cout << ++f;  // f is incremented then displayed.
```

In general, I prefer to use ++n over n++ unless the program logic requires the opposite.